# How to send matrix parameter to function from main in C++

Tags: c++, function, matrix, parameters, parameter-passing

I'm trying to send a matrix variable from my main() to a void function, but when I receive the parameter from the void function with (int grid[][], int num), I receive an error:

/home/ubuntu/workspace/home/game.cpp:13:24: error: declaration of ‘grid’ as multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the first

```
void column(int grid[][], int num){
                        ^

/home/ubuntu/workspace/home/game.cpp:13:25: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘,’ token
 void column(int grid[][], int num){

                         ^

/home/ubuntu/workspace/home/game.cpp:13:27: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘int’

 void column(int grid[][], int num){

                           ^
```

How can I send grid[][] to the void function as a parameter?

Comment: Hint: `int**` is the usual way. Given this is C++, don't pass in naked pointers or C-style arrays. Instead use containers like `std::vector` or `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` in this case.

Comment: The error is fairly self-explanatory, it wants `int grid[][size]` or `int (*grid)[size]` where `'size'` is an *integer constant*. Without a size in `grid` is a *incomplete type*. You can use a *pointer-to-pointer-to-type* as @tadman indicates above (or a container type).

Comment: since it's a matrix, I wonder to use `std::array`s maybe better than  using vectors?

Answer (score 2):

In C/C++ you can omit only the first dimension of an array when you pass it to a function:

```
int grid[][20]
```

since C/C++ does not have real multidimensional arrays, but just one dimensional arrays, in which address arithmetic is used to access an element in a given dimension.

Or you can follow @tadman suggestion from the comment and use

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > grid //or int** grid
```

Comment: Could have been better if you would have recommended use of `std::vector<std::vector<int> >` over this.